# How to Insert Images into an Email Message Body not as attachments?

Tags: php, html, html-email

i am working on a project where i have to send emails with images, but the problem is the image must be sent inside message body not as attachment, i have tried a lot from my side, but no result found. Please provide me some appropriate solution to sort out this problem.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Simple Dude, encode the image in base64 format and then append in message body with some separator :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a base64 string from the image and use this as the src.

```
$img = file_get_contents('image.jpg');
$img_b64 = base64_encode($img);

echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64," . $img_b64 . "' />";
```

If you use another kind of image files, you will have to use another mime type.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is the way to do it...

Comment: That works for normal HTML displayed with just about any modern browser but does not work with most email clients.